# How to find the joint pdf of $Z=X+Y$ and $W=\frac{X}{Y}$?

Tags: probability-distributions, problem-solving

I have a joint pdf:

$$
\begin{equation*}
f(x,y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
e^{-(x+y)} & \text{if }0< x < y \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}$$

I need to find the joint pdf of $Z$, $W$ where $Z=X+Y$ and $W=\frac{Y}{X}$.

I started by writing $P(Z\le z , W \le w)$, but I am not sure how to continue. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The joint density of $Z,W$ is, per the method of transformation,

$$f_{Z,W}(z,w)=f_{X,Y}\left(\frac z{1+w},\frac{zw}{1+w}\right)\frac z{(1+w)^2}$$

where $\frac z{(1+w)^2}$ is the (absolute value of the) Jacobian determinant for the transformation from the $(x,y)$ plane to the $(z,w)$ plane.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Is there any way to solve this without using Jacobian? For example fz,w(z,w) = P(Z<=z , W<=w ) => P (X+Y<=z , Y/X <=w )=>.....

Comment: I don't see why the distribution method (the one you started using) wouldn't work. I'd probably have used it myself if I didn't have to refresh my memory on it :)

Comment: ok thank you  lot !i will add your solution with jacobian as a second way to solve the exercise .